# LocalStorage isn't passing the number 9

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm am having problems with `localStorage`, my `localStorage` isn't passing the number 9. What can I do to resolve this problem?

I've tried so many things, but nothing works.

I am doing this:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  if (sessionStorage.pontos) {
    sessionStorage.pontos = Number(sessionStorage.pontos) + 1;
  } else {
    sessionStorage.pontos = 1;
  }

  document.getElementById('pontos').innerHTML = "PONTOS: " + sessionStorage.pontos;
} else {
  document.getElementById('pontos').innerHTML = "ERROR";
}
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  if (sessionStorage.pontos > localStorage.Recpontos) {
    localStorage.Recpontos = Number(localStorage.Recpontos) + 1;
  }
}
```

This action happen when click in a button.
And I go to the browser console, and nothing, in the console show this:

```
> localStorage.Recpontos
 "9"

> sessionStorage.pontos
 "10"
```

And it was not to be happening this, because when the `sessionStorage.pontos` is greater than `localStorage.Recpontos` was for the two to be in the same value. And `9` has only one place, and `10` has two, I think this is the problem.

I expected the `localStorage.Recpontos` will be added 1 when the `sessionStorage.point` is larger than it.

Comment: Do you realize you are comparing strings and not numbers? `"9" !== 9` try `console.log(10 > 9, "10" > "9")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the values as numbers, not strings.

```
  if (Number(sessionStorage.pontos) > Number(localStorage.Recpontos)) {
    localStorage.Recpontos = Number(localStorage.Recpontos) + 1;
  }
```

If you compare them as strings, it performs a lexicographic comparison, and `"10" < "9"` because `"1" < "9"`.